# Conda create an envrioment py3.7 with only installing jupyter, but founds conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

When I created a new environment like this: `conda create -n nb python=3.7 jupyter` , it failed.

The console told me:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.-
Examining jupyter: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.7
jupyter -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
jupyter -> ipywidgets -> python[version='>=3.5']
```

so I went to the base enviroment to check the installed packages for their versions. `(base) D:\>conda list`

the python version is 3.7.4, and the jupyter is 1.0.0. So I tried again. `conda create -n nb python=3.7.3 jupyter=1.0.0`

Yet, it still cannot work. I'm very confused. Why??

Here is the `conda info`

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Administrator\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Administrator\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I googled, but it seems noboday has got the problem like me. Why does this have to just happen to me.

please, I need some help.

Comment: Strange. It looks to me like something has gone wrong at Anaconda. For instance, `anaconda` is their flagship metapackage, and trying to install the latest Python 3.7 build for Windows fails along similar lines (e.g., `conda create -n foo -c defaults -c anaconda --override-channels anaconda/win-64::anaconda=2019.10=py37_0`). I would seek support on [Anaconda Issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues).

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Conda 4.7.12 or 4.8.2, on macOS 10.15.2.

Comment: @AMC I also tested on MacOS, but simulating for Windows - it seems to be Windows-specific. If you want to simulate a Windows install from a different platform, you can try: `CONDA_SUBDIR="win-64" conda create -n foo -d -c defaults --override-channels python=3.7 jupyter`

Comment: @merv Thank you. Since you said，I go to test another computer which installed anaconda a year ago and has not updated since then. yeah，It works fine. So anaconda-2019.10-x64-Windows version has something wrong in it. At first，I don't think the problem is theirs.For these reason：1. I'm not proficient in anaconda or python. 2. The lastest version was released 3 months ago.

Comment: @ChuckZhao To be clear, I only tried to install the `anaconda` package because I know that it has `python=3.7` and `jupyter` as dependencies, so I figured if what you reported is true, it means that `anaconda` is also broken, which seems to be the case. This is different from installing Anaconda 2019.10 from a binary, though, which I don't think is the issue. Instead, there is something amiss in Anaconda Cloud repositories that is preventing solving for this combination of packages. Likely they deprecated something that was a key constraint.

Comment: @merv Sorry, I may missunderstand you in the first place. After your last replies,I could understand more. So I tested again. Finally, I find out where does the problem come out. It should be the mirror takes the responsibility. I changed my channels from to Tsinghua Mirror to Anaconda. There was no conflicts. Apologize for my poor English and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @merv, with his help I located the problem is in the Tsinghua Anaconda Mirror. I have reported this to them. They reproduce this with `CONDA_SUBDIR="win-64"` command in MacOS.

The issue page:
https://github.com/tuna/issues/issues/701

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation shows that the root cause is the lack of `/pkgs/msys2` channel in `default_channels:` of `.condarc` file, which results in package `m2w64-gcc-libs` not found, then possibly confuses the conda dependency resolver.

I holp this finding would help people who meet similarly weird dependency conflicts.